# Add "category name" to a "prev/next" link on a blog post?

Tags: wordpress

Looking for a little Wordpress help, I've created "prev/next" links when viewing a post which will take you to the next post and previous post. I wanted to attach the category that, that specific post is related to.

For example:

Next Baseball Card Dealer or Prev Stolen Baseballs

So, Baseball Car Dealer and Stolen Baseballs are categories that I want shown.

Here's the code I'm using to generate the Next/Prev links:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>">« Prev</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function you need to get the category name, sorry bout formatting, on my mobile:

$category = get_the_category( $prev_post->ID );
echo $category[0]->cat_name;

Comment: Thank you! Did exactly what I needed. Appreciate it.